# Android Speech Recognition: How to address problems like hyphenated words, compound words, apostrophes, etc. in matching spoken word with stored word?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I am trying to implement the speech recognition in android.

Here I have a paragraph set to TextView.
I have array list of words split by " " blank space.
I am using onPartialResult to get words spoken by user.
we get input words like this

```
[I]
[I am]
[I am android]
[I am android user]
```

so i am converting that to arraylist of words by splitting by space
and taking only last element of array. so every time i will get only new word.

now on getting new word i have to match it with arraylist of words from paragraph.

I have a global index which keeps increasing on matching.
also on matching i take indexs in paragraph text of TextView using spannable.
Then set color to that matched word.

The problem:

1. there are words as here-there with hyphen(-)
   How can we detect and match it. because spoken words are

```
[here]
[here there]
```

For now it seems after splitting by empty space I also have to check such symbole and split it again.

2. There is another word carefree which does not macthes easily because
   spoken words are care, free separately.
3. Then there are words like day's while spoken word is always days.
   Although I fixed this by checking words having 's and replace it with spoken word like day(s) to day('s)
4. Can we have any algorithm or library which matches the words without manipulating the spoken word or stored words.
   There might be more such issues. handling this manually is time consuming and makes detection slower.

What would be the good solution for detection and matching words.

Spannable text and textview text content should be same so that we can apply color correctly. so while matching we cant modify the texts of paragraph we used to display.

This is code i am using right now

```java
  private void applyColor(String param){
        ArrayList<String> params = paraToArray(param);
        // from string only get last word
        String newWord = params.get(params.size()-1);
        // get current word of paragraph by using global index tracking 
        String currentWord_FromParagraph = paragraphWords.get(indexHistory);

        // handle 's words
        if(currentWord_FromParagraph.contains("'s")){
            String rootWord = currentWord_FromParagraph.replaceAll("'s\\b", "");
            newWord = rootWord+"'s";
        }
        
        // index of word on paragraph
        int start = paragraph.indexOf(newWord, indexHistoryChar);
        int end = newWord.length();
        
        // match
        if(start != -1 && newWord.equalsIgnoreCase(currentWord_FromParagraph) ){
            // spannable contains paragraph and its global 
             spannableString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GREEN), start, 
             start+end, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            // global index for array of words of paragraph. after matching ignore current index so we look for next word
            indexHistory++;
            // similar as above but it is for paragraph character index
            indexHistoryChar = start+end;


            spannableString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.WHITE), startNext, endNext, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        }

        txtv_paragraph.setText(spannableString);

    }
```

Comment: I found some algorithms and it works for 's, word:, word:-, word., etc. but still we have issue of getting separate words while we need single word like carefree become care, free even user says carefree quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for matching similar sounding words.
apache's Soundex and another is Metaphone3 by Google
It easily matches the words like
or == our,
kishor's == kishor,
days == day's
by == bye
y == why
stack.: == stack
(I got above matching using Metaphone3, while Soundex does not match some words even like y and why, but matches bye==bye, or==our)
you can tweak more by usage of contains and equals according to usage.

**For Soundex of apache**
add this to build.gradle

```
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec
    implementation 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.16.0'
```

**For Metaphone3**
Use this class and call its function. you need to remove main method and package name to use it as Module
https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/blob/master/main/src/com/google/refine/clustering/binning/Metaphone3.java

But still there is one issue remained which is to handling word splitting by speech recognition while we have word as single word. i.e. we have 'carefree' but recognition returns [care, free].
So need to handle it.